# Why the decal making background black

Tags: texturing, materials

I have 2 Material Gray and Black. On the top of gray material i want to place my decal (logo). So that i can see my background (gray material) on top my logo. I have my node setup seen below. Why im getting black background. Any suggestion. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: You aren't using the images alpha properly. https://artisticrender.com/how-to-use-alpha-transparent-textures-in-blender/

Comment: when i start your provided blend file and check the rendered view - font is black and background is white - did you change the blend file before or after you made the screenshot?

Comment: is your render engine set to cycles?

Comment: @gladys yes its cycles

Comment: I don't see the grey material in your node set up. I think you need a mix node and add the grey material.